# Routing configuration in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, routes

I am building a application in codeigniter and is running in some issues with routes.
I want that if someone punch in this url: www.mywebsite.com/request-information, a controller called 'myform' should be called.

I am configuring routes file as this:

$route['request-information']='leadform';

But this doesn't work with hyphen, may be due to regex interference.

Please guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is from a project of mine and works just fine:

```
$route['unlock-account/(:num)/(:any)'] = 'auths/unlock_account/$1/$2';
```

Make sure your mistake dosn't come from another place. What is the error message, where is it routing you to?

Answer (score 0):

I see nothing in that line that would make it load `myform`.

Have you tried

```
$route['request-information']='myform';
```

or

```
$route['request\-information']='myform';
```

Comment: $route['request-information']='myform';

This is the line i am using. i just quoted that for example. 
nyways, $route['request\-information']='myform'; isn't working as well.

Comment: Print the address you're trying and given base_url, and do define what isn't working. I can't see your screen.